# Upload File HTTP Post

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, file-upload

I'm using a form with a file input to POST to a different page with the target as an iframe. I'm coding in C# ASP.NET. I have the file posting fine, but don't know how to handle it on the server side. What code do I use to take the POST data and save it as a file on the server? After that, I can manipulate it and delete it with System.IO.

Comment: What have you tried? A little googling would trivially answer this with `Request.Files`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the postback of your iframe, enumerate over `Request.Files` and call `Request.Files[index].SaveAs(string filename)` to write it to the disk in the location of your choice.

Comment: Thanks. I kept finding results for using FileUpload with ASP.NET when it's a same page postback. This is exactly what I needed. Can the file be grabbed by ID instead of index? ex Request.Files["FILEID"].SaveAs("filename");

Comment: Assuming FILEID is the name of your file input, yes, that will also work.